# Working with itertools.product and lists in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm trying to create a possible list of codons given a protein sequence.

Basically, the script i'm trying to create will process a given string input and outputs a possible combinations of another set of strings the input represents.

For example, the character 'F' represents either 'UUU' or 'UUC'; the character 'I' represents either 'AUU', 'AUC', or 'AUA'.

Given the input 'FI', the script I'm trying to create should output:
'UUUAUU', 'UUUAUC', 'UUUAUA', 'UUCAUU', 'UUCAUC', and 'UUCAUA'.

I'm currently stuck with this code:

```
import itertools

F = ['UUU', 'UUC']
I = ['AUU', 'AUC', 'AUA']

seq, pool = 'FI', []

for i in seq:
   pool.append(eval(i))

for n in itertools.product(pool):
   print(n)
```

It works when I replace `pool` in `itertools.product` with `pool[0], pool[1]`. But I can't figure out how to make it work so that the user can input a string with more than 2 character (i.e. not to make it hard-coded).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `*pool` to "unpack" the list when calling `product()`:

```
for n in itertools.product(*pool):
   print(n)
```

This syntax expands the list `pool` into separate positional parameters.

Answer (score 3):

itertools.product(pool[0],pool[1],...pool[len(pool)-1]) is equivalent to itertools.product(*pool)

```
import itertools

F = ['UUU', 'UUC']
I = ['AUU', 'AUC', 'AUA']

pool=[F,I]

for n in itertools.product(*pool):
   print(''.join(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (in my opinion more often) the list does not need a printout:

```
F = ['UUU', 'UUC']
I = ['AUU', 'AUC', 'AUA']

pool=[F,I]
lista = []

for n in itertools.product(*pool):
      lista.append(''.join(n))

lista
```

[image]